# dual boot laptop: Windows 10 runs 2 screens at 3840x2160; ubuntu limits 2nd screen to 1920x1080

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have Asus laptop with an Intel i7 (includes on chip 620 graphics) plus an additional Nvidia 950m chip.  It dual boots:

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 18.04

In Windows I have no trouble getting 3840x2160 on both the built-in hi-res sceen and an HDMI-connected LG 27UD69-M monitor.  Both screens are naturally 16:9.  Once I boot into Ubuntu, try as I may, I cannot get the LG screen configured for more than 1920x1080.

It appears that Windows is not using the Nvidia chip (the display properties report that they are both using the Intel graphics driver.)

In Ubuntu I have blacklisted the nouveau driver, purged and reinstalled the Nvidia packages, purged again in hope of perhaps using the Intel driver (a la Windows).  All to no avail.

What am I missing?